# how to upload a laravel project on server for clients

Tags: php, laravel

I have developed a `MVC` project with `Laravel` 5.4. Whenever I want to develop it on localhost, I use `php artisan serve` command to access it via localhost:8000 on browser. Now I have uploaded the project on a `linux` server with centos 6 and I run `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 to access it via x.x.x.x:8080` on browser but it is a temporary way to access project from browser. What is the permanent way to access a `laravel` project by clients via public IP?

I have apache,php and ... separately installed on my server. I can not see x.x.x.x/projectname/public or x.x.x.x/projectname. The project is in /var/www/html directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the laravel project with `yoursite.com/projectname/public` if you upload your project on web root.

If you want to access it directly with `yoursite.com` you need to map the public folder in your virtual host configuration.

```
# The location of our projects public directory.
DocumentRoot    /path/to/your/public
```

Comment: I have apache,php and ... separately installed in my server. I can not see x.x.x.x/projectname/public, I get 404 not found error. The project is in /var/www/html directory.

Comment: Can you access with yoursite.com/public?

Comment: No . I can not.

Answer (score 0):

On your linux server install the `LAMP` or `XAMP` that include the apache server and Mysql and some other related tools into it. Upload the code on web root. Now try to access it with the IP or the domain name like:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/projectname/public
```

or

```
or domain/projectname/public
```

Note: You can remove that public by making a symlink to the public directory or by making a virtual host entry.

Comment: I have apache,php and ... separately installed in my server. I can not see x.x.x.x/projectname/public, I get 404 not found error. The project is in /var/www/html directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to do [assuming you are using apache, but its not very different for nginx]:

- install PHP, MySQL and apache in your server
- place your project in /var/www/ folder
- give permission to storage folder of your project `chmod -R 777 your/project/storage`
- edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file e.g. `DocumentRoot    /path/to/your/public`
- restart apache

Please check other answers. They are very good and give you a clear starting point. Just do little research and you will get it.